# How to open a particular file inside an iframe, from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How to open a particular file inside an iframe, from a link

> For example;
>   http://ccgi.vaegar.force9.co.uk/examples/SwingSet2_demo/index.html

I want to navigate to ButtonDemo, when opening a link, how it possible

I have tried following ways,but not worked

```
<a href="http://ccgi.vaegar.force9.co.uk/examples/SwingSet2_demo/index.html?target=ButtonDemo.java.html">ButtonDemo</a>

<a href="http://ccgi.vaegar.force9.co.uk/examples/SwingSet2_demo/index.html?ButtonDemo.java.html">ButtonDemo</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no iframe in the example you provided. Please explain specifically what you require

Comment: I need to click a link and it should navigate to particular file inside iframe

Comment: You mean when you click the link, the file should OPEN in the iFrame? is that what you are saying? that's simple name your iframe and use it as a target for the link `<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>`

`<a href="your_link_here" target="iframe_a">Site</a> `

Comment: I have tried your example, it is creating another iframe but it is not required. In my case iframe is already have in the above site (http://ccgi.vaegar.force9.co.uk/examples/SwingSet2_demo/index.html). By clicking an external link it need to open ButtonDemo inside that frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your iframe has the name attribute sat to, for example `name="myFrame"`, then you can use the target attribute on your anchor tags `target="myFrame"`

```
<a target="myFrame" href="http://ccgi.vaegar.force9.co.uk/examples/SwingSet2_demo/index.html">ButtonDemo</a>

<a target="myFrame" href="http://ccgi.vaegar.force9.co.uk/examples/SwingSet2_demo/index.html">ButtonDemo</a>
```

And your iframe

```
<iframe name="myFrame" ></iframe>
```

[Here's](https://plnkr.co/edit/vuwPz2tYLAny4IUiL5XH?p=preview) a working example on plunker

Comment: Can you show me an example with above context, I have tried with below but no luck <a target="packageFrame" href="http://ccgi.vaegar.force9.co.uk/examples/SwingSet2_demo/index.html">ButtonDemo</a>

Comment: @javaspecialist Added a plunker link to my answer